# How to get auto-resizing of ttk Element in tkinter UI properly tied to root window resizing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to have a gracefully resizable TK user interface holding a `ttk.Notebook`. Meaning: If the window is dragged larger, the content should increase its size accordingly.

The first naive attempt was using the **sticky** parameter of the grid mechanism:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
[..]
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.grid(row=j, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
```

I had expected this to suffice, alas it had no effect. Eventually I resorted to configuration events:

```py
root.bind('<Configure>', handle_resize)  # << Btw. is there a way to restrict this to resize events?

def handle_resize(ev):
  if ev.width:
    width = root.winfo_width()
    notebook.config(width=width - 4)  # << Consider the fragile "-4" atrocity in this line!
```

If that dubious **-4** is lacking, the Notebook will be a little too broad -- causing a resize -- causing an update that again is a little to broad, in theory ad infinitum! In practice creating a window that grows a little broader all the time until strange things happen.

Hence that **-4**, actually solving the problem on my PC. But this feels so very fragile! The question:

How do I go about **properly** auto-resizing the `ttk.Notebook`?

Comment: You need to add `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` and the binding is not required then.

Comment: Will yet have to read the doc for that hitherto unknown-to-me root-function. Right away I can say that it does actually solve my problem. So thank you very much! Why don't you put it into a proper answer that I might accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you tell the grid manager to make the `notebook` to take up all the horizontal space of the cell, but you don't tell the grid manager to make the *cell* (column 0) to take up all the available horizontal space of the root window.

It can be done by adding `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Note that with the above line, the binding is not required.

Comment: Now I even understand it. Thx again! :-)

Comment: P.S.: This even works for the ttk.Frames inside the ttk.Notebook.